# Object get's casted

Tags: c#, web-services

For the company I'm working, I need to fetch and save some data via webservices.

I developed an api where I can:

- Get the data there via a webservice called `QueryService`
- Save the data via a webservice called `ObjectService`

Both objects have a class called `Attribute` that looks like this:

```
public partial class Attribute {

    private string nameField;

    private object valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for this situation that's causing some problems is like following:

```
List<myApp.ObjectService.Attribute> properties = new List<myApp.ObjectService.Attribute>();

properties.Add(
    new myApp.ObjectService.Attribute() {
        Name = "object_name",
        Value = g.Name
    }
);
properties.Add(
    new myApp.ObjectService.Attribute() {
        Name = "title",
        Value = g.Name
    }
);
properties.Add(
    new myApp.ObjectService.Attribute() {
        Name = "m_video_st",
        Value = g.Videos.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray()
    }
);
properties.Add(
    new myApp.ObjectService.Attribute() {
        Name = "keywords",
        Value = g.Keywords.ToArray()
    }
);
myApp.ObjectService.Attribute[] arr = properties.ToArray();
os.Save(g.Id, arr);
```

`os` is being created in the contstructor of that class:

```
this.os = new myApp.ObjectService.Objectservice();
```

when testing this locally (the service is referencing the same server on local machine and deploy machine) it works great and When I use Fiddler to look at the request send from the api to the serveice it looks like this:
[image]

But when I deploy the request  looks like this:
[image]

notice where the keywords attribute changed from `xsi:type=ArrayOfString` to `xmlns:q2=http://xxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/queryservices xsi:type=q2:ArrayOfString ]`

So it's changing from the list type for some reason.

Here we think it's from IIS. But we have no clue why.